# copy worksheet from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-docs, gdata

Is it possible to copy spreadsheets with gdata API or worksheets from one spreadsheet to other? For now i copy all cells from one worksheet to another. One cell per request. It is too slow. I read about "cell batch processing" and write this code:

```
src_key = 'rFQqEnFWuR6qoU2HEfdVuTw'; dst_key = 'rPCVJ80MHt7K2EVlXNqytLQ'

sheetcl = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService('x@gmail.com','p')
dcs = gdata.docs.service.DocsService('x@gmail.com', 'p')

src_worksheets = sheetcl.GetWorksheetsFeed(src_key)
dst_worksheets = sheetcl.GetWorksheetsFeed(dst_key)

for src_worksheet, dst_worksheet in zip(src_worksheets.entry, dst_worksheets.entry):

    sheet_id = src_worksheet.id.text.split('/')[-1]
    dst_sheet_id = dst_worksheet.id.text.split('/')[-1]

    cells_feed = sheetcl.GetCellsFeed(src_key, sheet_id)
    dst_cells_feed = sheetcl.GetCellsFeed(dst_key, dst_sheet_id)

    for cell in cells_feed.entry:
        dst_cells_feed.AddInsert(cell)

    sheetcl.ExecuteBatch(dst_cells_feed, dst_cells_feed.GetBatchLink().href)
```

But it doesn't work. As I suppose reason is that each cell in inner loop has its id which consist of spreadsheet_id:

```
>>> cell.id.text
'http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/rFQqEnFWuR6qoU2HEfdVuTw/default/private/full/R1C1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be using a [cell range query](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#cellsQueryExample) to get a whole row at a time, then [inserting rows](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#addRow) in the target spreadsheet.